# Prove that $EF=\sqrt{3} AB$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

On a semicircle with diameter $AB$ and centre $S$, points $C$ and $D$ are given such that point $C$ belongs to arc $AD$. Suppose $\angle CSD=120^{\circ}$. Let $E$ be the point of intersection of the straight lines $AC$ and $BD$ and $F$ be the point of intersection of the straight lines $AD$ and $BC$. Prove that $EF=\sqrt{3} AB$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $\measuredangle ACB =\measuredangle ADB =90^{\circ}$ cause are angles inscribed in a semicircle. So $F$ is the orthocenter of the triangle $ABE$, it follows that $EF$ is perpendicular to $AB$, so the triangles $\triangle ECF$ and $\triangle BCA$ are similar since their sides are perpendicular. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{|EF|}{|AB|}&=\frac{|CF|}{|CA|}\\
&=\tan \measuredangle CAF\\
&=\tan \left(\frac{\measuredangle CSD}{2}\right)\\
&=\tan 60^{\circ}\\
&=\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}
[image]